# The best way of combining a picture with textboxes

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I've gotten a task which I feel I really don't know the best approach for.
So here I am, asking for your help and opinions.

I've been assigned to create a form on a webpage (ASP.NET WebForms) with multiple textboxes
where people should fill in different measures. The textboxes are to be placed on top of a schematic sketch over the measured object in question, hence the textboxes won't be positioned in a straight vertical alignment but can be

The way I've done it so far is by having it grouped as follows:

- Div with the background image (relative positioning)

  - Div with measurement texbox (absolute positioning)

Now, while this works, is there another way of achieving this or is this the best way?

I haven't dabbled to much in HTML5 and maybe there are something that can be utilized there?

Your help and opinions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set the image as a background. And place the textboxes in that div positioned absolutely, then using top, left, or bottom depending on where you want the image to sit.

Comment: Looks good, maybe use Cam's advise. I only wonder what would happen if you watch the site on a screen with a resolution that is lower than the image's size

Comment: GroundZero: I don't Think that will be an issue, the image in question is about 300px wide and 450px high. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is common practice and definitely what most people would advise. I don't think HTML 5 has anything new to offer here.